# Should I use SQLite3 bind_int function?

Tags: c++, sqlite

is there any reason that I should use sqlite3_bind_int() function? Is it ok to pass integer variables before Prepare function execution?

Example A (pseudocode):

```
// prepare statement
sstream s;
s << "insert into TABLE values(" << 1 << "," << 2 << ",?)";
//...
const char *sql = ... // sql is equal to "insert into TABLE values(1, 2, ?)";
Prepare(..., sql, ...);
sqlite3_bind_text(3, "text")
```

Example B (pseudocode):

```
const char *sql = "insert into TABLE values(?, ?, ?)";
Prepare(..., sql, ...);
sqlite3_bind_int(1, 1);
sqlite3_bind_int(2, 2);
sqlite3_bind_text(3, "text")
```

I understand that text variables can contain SQL Injection string, so I should use bind_text function, but integers?

Comment: No it's not ok. You must have a prepared statement to bind the values to. If you don't have a prepared statement it will not work.

Comment: I have checked that and it works. I prepared the "insert into TABLE values(1, 2, ?)" and call Prepare(), then bind_text.  Numbers and were added to table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding parameters avoids formatting problems or SQL injection attacks.

However, neither is a problem for plain integers.
So you don't really *need* to use `sqlite3_bind_int`, if the other code is easier for you.

On the other hand, you definitely want to use binding for float/text/blob values, so it's likely that avoiding `sqlite3_bind_int` just makes the code inconsistent.